# Getting rid of an extra dot in the numbering of my new float environment?

Tags: floats, captions, biber

I declared a new environment like this:

```
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    name=Diagramm,
    listname=Liste von Diagrammen,
]{diagram}
```

And using it works fine, except for an extra dot that appears in the caption after the counter:

[image: Extra dot in the caption]

I attempted to get rid of the dot by using `\captionsetup[diagram]{format=plain,labelsep=space}` but this of only affects the colon after the counter.

So I tried  `\renewcommand{\thediagram}{\arabic{diagram}}` which didn't change anything about the dot at all. If I however insert some gobblydonk in with every occurence of the numbering (like `\renewcommand{\thediagram}{\arabic{diagram} ASDF}`) the `ASDF` gets rendered just fine.

The default environments I use (`figure` and `table`) do not have this extra dot, how could I remove it from my custom environment?

**Update**: While attempting to build a minimal example I stumbled over some very strange side-effects. If I do an entirely clean build everything is fun, but in the run after `biber` has run I get the dot pictured above. So I don't think this can be easily reproduced on another machine, but I will give it a try.

Not using `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` but `\newfloat` instead also works just fine:

```
\newfloat{umldiagram}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{umldiagram}{Diagramm}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Will do, getting this really minimal will take a little, I was hoping somebody could immediately tell that I am missing something obvious.

Comment: I assume a KOMA-Script class is used? If yes, the `newfloat` package respects the auto-dot feature of KOMA-Script. (You should get the same dot with `figure` and `table`. If not, just do the same to `umldiagram` as you have done to `figure` and `table`.)

Comment: ...and if you want to use the `caption` package to get rid of the dot, you can either use `\captionsetup{labelformat=simple}` or `\captionsetup[umldiagram]{labelformat=simple}`. This will override the default setting which is given by KOMA-Script.

Comment: +1 to the issue - was an answer ever determined?

Comment: Sorry, I never got around really getting to the bottom of this. I settled for some manual hacking with `\newfloat` in the end.

Comment: @MarcusRiemer For me, the problem occurred when I incorporated the `biblatex` package, possibly when I set it to the `biber` backend. (I'm using a KOMA class: `scrreprt`)  At this point, I had not yet run `biber.exe`, and I may have run `bibtex.exe` at some point.  Anyway, when I ran `biber.exe`, after finally understanding that you don't run `biblatex` - you run `bibtex` or `biber` while using `biblatex` - the problem disappeared.

Comment: I've had this issue without biblatex.
Not a proper solution, but one can manually redefine (after defining the float) what the numbers are formatted like using `\def\fnum@umldiagram{Diagramm~\arabic{umldiagram}}`